# Swift: Adding Headers to my REST POST Request

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am still learning Swift and I am trying to make a POST request to my web service via my new iOS App written in Swift.

I need to know how to add 2 headers to my already existing code. Also am I adding the parameters correctly?

What I have so far:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://MY-MOBILE-SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/api/login");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

// Compose a query string
   
let postString = "email=myemail@website.com&password=123";

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    
    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    
    print("response = \(response)")
}

task.resume()
```

Here are the Headers I need to add to this request:

> **X-ZUMO-APPLICATION**: 45634243542434
>
> **ACCEPT**: application/json

How do I attach these headers to my request?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you opened the documentation for [`NSMutableURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/) you would find the relevant method.

Comment: You should find that easily in the docs as @jcaron said. Also, you might want to take a look to Alamofire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use alamofire, this should work, it also eases things for you so you choose get or post

```
var pars2 : Dictionary<String,String> = ["api_key":"value"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "someURLString" ,parameters: pars2).responseJSON()
{
        (request, response, data, error) in
        if(data != nil)
        {
            self.countryIDArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            var status = data!["status"]!! as! String
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the reference docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:

so you would do: `request.setValue("ACCEPT" forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")`